# Synthesis tool free-source

Tags: fpga, vhdl, simulation, synthesis

I'm currently learning VHDL and to simulate the code that I write I found out GHDL (open-source), which I haven't tried yet but I think does what it needs to be done.

In order to synthesize the VDHL code into any FPGA, is there any free Synthesis tool or are they all vendor specific (and hence paid)? It would be great to find a general one which allowed to program into any FPGA since I still don't know on which FPGA I'll need to work and since each tool has a steep learning curve - I speak from personal experience with Xilinx's Vivado.

Comment: They are all vendor-specific, and there's very little that's OSS - but you don't need a synthesis tool to develop a design in VHDL, only a simulator.

Comment: Yes but as I understand there are many things which simulate and don't synthesize.

Comment: That's true, but it's fairly easy to restrict yourself to the synthesizable subset of VHDL - which is pretty much the same no matter which vendor's tools you're eventually synthesizing with.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/)

Comment: Ty for the answer @EugeneSh. , very good link. But that's only for simulation right? Not synthesis.

Comment: There are a couple of synthesizers under the "tools". I think they are open-source, so you can look them up separately. Not sure they are production ready, though..

Comment: None of the comments yet have pointed out that most FPGA vendors offer free versions of their tools, and these are not cripple-ware but very capable tools  - just not open source. Certainly true of Xilinx, Altera, Microsemi. The biggest problem is they tend to be multi-GB downloads. If you have Vivado, that counts. Synthesisable subsets differ in details, but are all broadly similar.

Comment: Add to what Brian Drummond said -- FPGA are not just a sea of gates of fine granularity, using the vendor specific synthesizers give you the best chances of optimized implementation. To know how to write synthesizable code is part of the "program" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use an open source simulator (iverilog) in combination with manufacturer supplied toolchains (xilinx ise, altera quartus).  The verilog code I write avoids FPGA specific primitives so that it can be simulated with open source tools and then ported to whatever FPGA I need to run it on.  The manufacturer's tools are pretty much the best you can get for most of the parts out there.  Now, I use FPGAs that are large enough to require licenses for the software, but if you stick to the smaller FPGAs and don't need any of the vendor-supplied IP cores, then the free versions of the tools work just fine (generally the only restrictions on the free version are the supported devices, IP library, specialized features like floorplanning and partial reconfiguration, and on-chip debugging features).

There are some open source tools for synthesis/place and route, but the device support for these are extremely limited.

Comment: Ty for the answer. As to the open source simulator, `iverilog`, I already used it when learning Verilog. But tell me something, does it also run VHDL?

Comment: No, but try ghdl.